# Creating multiple select checkboxes with Django

Tags: python, django, checkbox

I'm getting a little problem with `multiple checkboxes` according to Django models & forms.
I'm creating a template which let to select a theme which will apply on my project. I already scripted a list of theme with identicals css files but with different background-colors.

**Objective :** Users check the box, Django picks up the variable and the css path is modified according to this variable. Then one of theme is applied.

I created a `models.py` file :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import force_text

# 2 themes : Datasystems & Cameroun
FAVORITE_THEME = (
    ('Datasystems', 'Datasystems'),
    ('Cameroun', 'Cameroun'),
)

class Theme(models.Model):

    favorite_theme = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=FAVORITE_THEME)
```

Then my `forms.py` file :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django import forms
from .models import Theme


class ThemeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    favorite_theme = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        label = "Choisissez le thème à appliquer",
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Theme
        fields = '__all__'
```

The `views.py` file is very simple :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
from django.shortcuts import render, reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse

from .forms import ThemeForm
from .models import Theme

def Theme(request) :

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = ThemeForm(request.POST or None)

        if 'save' in request.POST :
            post = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Theme_selected'))

    else:
        form = ThemeForm()

    context = {
        "form":form,
    }

    return render(request, 'Theme.html', context)
```

And finally my `template.html` which just displays the form :

```
{% extends 'Base_Configurations.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}

<style>
    .form {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

        <form class = "form" method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}
                <h3> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> Choix du thème DatasystemsEC </h3>
                <br></br>
                {{ form }} 
                <br></br>
                <input class="button" type ="submit" name="save" value="Valider le thème" /> 
        </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

**My problem is :** I don't arrive to display my form in my template page with correct checkboxes.

I watched this tutorials or SO questions :

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/
- http://blog.ekini.net/2011/03/09/django-creating-multiple-select-checkboxes-with-forms/

Thank you if you could help me !

**EDIT :**

I deleted my models.py file and my forms.py file looks like this (according to @DanielRoseman answer) :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django import forms

FAVORITE_THEME = (
    ('Datasystems', 'Datasystems'),
    ('Cameroun', 'Cameroun'),
)

class ThemeForm(forms.Form):
    favorite_theme = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FAVORITE_THEME, label = "Choisissez le thème à appliquer", widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

Comment: Are you sure you want multiple checkboxes? It looks from the model as though the user can only select a single favourite theme; radio buttons would be better for that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's the first time I'm thinking about this kind of things. So i'm not sure ^^ Form my point of view, the form just has one line with several case : Datasystems Theme - Cameroun Theme - ... User checks one case and the global theme takes account the variable name. I don't know if I'm really comprehensible :/

Comment: Yes, are you still having any problems?

Comment: Some little problems : `'ThemeForm' object has no attribute 'save'` for example. Then I have to see How I can pick up the variable and modify the static path according to the selected theme ^^ 

I think I have to try using a ModelForm instead of a Form